# move only if file exists in a shell script

Tags: linux, sh, mv

I want to use `mv` to rename a file:

```
mv src.txt dest.txt
```

If the file doesn't exist, I get an error:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘src.txt’: No such file or directory
```

How do I use `mv` only if the file already exists?

I don't want to redirect *stderr* to `dev/null` as I'd like to keep any other errors that occur

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should test if the file exists

```
if [ -f blah ]; then
   mv blah destination
fi
```

Comment: @Oz123 to be pedantic need to use `[ -r blah ]`, for additional check in read permision

Comment: Only -r worked for me even though the problem was that the file wasn't there at all.

Comment: @SergA, in that particuliar case, wouldn't ````[ -w blah ]```` be more appropriate since ````mv```` needs write permissions over the file?

Comment: @ghilesZ, actually there is no need to check write and read file permissions. To move file *you need to have permission to detach it from the directory where it was before, and to attach it to the directory where you're putting it*. Got from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149798/170894).

Comment: For directories use `[ -d myDir ]`.

Answer (score 107):

One-liner:

```
[ -f old ] && mv old nu
```

Comment: Note that you have to remember to keep the spaces by the brackets. "[-f old]" not working was a surprise for me, who is more used to whitespace-insensitive languages

Comment: @jakebeal True. The `[` here is actually shorthand  for `test`, so the rest (before &) are plain old space-separated arguments like you’d pass to any shell command.

Answer (score 85):

This one liner **returns successfully** even if the file is not found:

```
[ ! -f src ] || mv src dest
```

Comment: (@mahemoff's version returns false if the file is not found.)

Comment: ```[ ! -d src ] || mv src dest```
if it's a folder

Comment: I was getting failure notifications in a VS Code tasks running @mahemoff's version. Now I know why. Thanks for the fix.