# move or copy a file if that file exists?

Tags: linux, centos, mv

I am trying to run a command

```
mv /var/www/my_folder/reports.html /tmp/
```

it is running properly. But I want to put a condition like if that file exists then only run the command. Is there anything like that?

I can put a shell file instead.
for shell a tried below thing

```
if [ -e /var/www/my_folder/reports.html ]
  then
  mv /var/www/my_folder/reports.html /tmp/
fi
```

But I need a command. Can some one help me with this?

Comment: Why exactly do you need a command?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [move only if file exists in a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414768/move-only-if-file-exists-in-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Moving the file `/var/www/my_folder/reports.html` only if it exists and regular file:

```
[ -f "/var/www/my_folder/reports.html" ] && mv "/var/www/my_folder/reports.html" /tmp/
```

- `-f` - returns `true` value if file exists and regular file

Comment: What if the file doesn't? Does it throw an error and change the status code from 0 to 1 or returns false (which isn't mean the command was broken with an error)?

Comment: @uzay95 No, it just returns false.

Answer (score 7):

If the file exists and then move or echo messages through standard error output:

```bash
test -e /var/www/my_folder/reports.html && mv /var/www/my_folder/reports.html /tmp/ || echo "not existing the file" >&2
```

Comment: It is also throwing same thing.

Comment: I was some late to answer your question than @RomanPerekhrest. you can see my answered time :|

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your use case is "Create if not exist, then copy always". 
Then:

```bash
touch myfile && cp myfile mydest/
```

Comment: `touch myfile` will create a file if it does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply in a shell script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check for the file
ls /var/www/my_folder/ | grep reports.html > /dev/null

# check output of the previous command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  # echo -e "Found file"
  mv /var/www/my_folder/reports.html /tmp/
else
  # echo -e "File is not in there"
fi
```

Hope it helps